# My script won't work in IE (even 9)? simple javascript to amend copy text

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I was browsing the internet one day, and copied a chunk of text "**my cool text**" and pasted it to facebook, only to see that it changed it to "**my cool text - Read More at *URL***", I was in awe! That's awesome!

So I dove in a little and found some tutorials and such. I took to my own to convert it to a customizable plugin with dozens of options, and it outputs this (or similar based on options):

```
function copyCopyright() {
    var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var selection;
    selection = window.getSelection();
    var copyrightLink = '<br /><br />Read more at: '+document.location.href+'<br /> &copy;2012  ';
    var copytext = selection + copyrightLink;
    var extraDiv = document.createElement("div");
    extraDiv.style.position="absolute";
    extraDiv.style.left="-99999px";
    theBody.appendChild(extraDiv);
    extraDiv.innerHTML = copytext;
    selection.selectAllChildren(extraDiv);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        theBody.removeChild(extraDiv);
    },0);
}
document.oncopy = copyCopyright;​
```

works GREAT in Chrome and Firefox, etc. But of COURSE it doesn't work in IE (even IE9!). I'm fairly new to Javascript, especially hunting down IE problems with it.

Is there a function or method or something above that IE just won't recognize that I'll have to find an alternate way around?

Comment: Chrome and Firefox throw an error free console. IE throws "SEC7115" which is just a simple CSS error regarding `:link` and `:visited`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE needs

```
document.body.oncopy=copyCopyright
```

added to your onload event. (body doesn’t exist until loaded)

Comment: You sir, are absolutely wonderful! Thanks!
I'll accept it when it lets me :)

Comment: Though, it appears to only work in IE9? Is there something else I'm missing for prior versions (I'm not SUPER concerned with that though)