# window.location.href doesn't yield the exact url

Tags: javascript

For some reason in my javascript the window.location.href returns only the domain name and not the current page address.

```
function addLink() {
    console.log('hey');
    var body_element = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    var selection;
    selection = window.getSelection();

    // added lines begin
    var htmlDiv = document.createElement("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < selection.rangeCount; ++i) {
        htmlDiv.appendChild(selection.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents()); 
    } 
    var selectionHTML = htmlDiv.innerHTML;    
    // added lines end

    var pagelink = "<br /><br />Read more: " + window.location.href + " <br />";
    var copytext = selectionHTML + pagelink; // <------------------- changed line

    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.style.position='absolute';
    newdiv.style.left='-99999px';
    body_element.appendChild(newdiv);
    newdiv.innerHTML = copytext;
    selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        body_element.removeChild(newdiv);
    }, 0);
} 
document.oncopy = addLink;
```

The file is active on http://www.chefsuccess.com
thanks!

Comment: It seems working properly.Can you give us the reproducing procedure?

Comment: Try to isolate the exact problem. Cut away all the page-specific things. See if you can reproduce in a clean environment. It seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/qbwjho58/

Comment: If I go to: http://www.chefsuccess.com/threads/find-a-consultant-changing.82540/

And copy some text, here is what is pasted. I don't get the page address.  

Read more: http://www.chefsuccess.com

The script also doesn't seem to work in IE.

Answer (score 2):

[My script won't work in IE (even 9)? simple javascript to amend copy text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048477/my-script-wont-work-in-ie-even-9-simple-javascript-to-amend-copy-text)

Perhaps you could find answer on above link.

IE needs

`document.body.oncopy=copyCopyright`

added to your onload event. (body doesn’t exist until loaded)