# window.location.href return domain name instead of full URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

`domain = window.location.href;`

Now the issues are that sometime this function works and it returns **full website URL**. And sometimes it's not working and it returning website **domain** instead of **full website URL**

I need always to return **full website URL**!

How can I solve it? 
There is another way to always get the **website's full URL**?

Comment: When does it return one and when the other?

Comment: @VLAZ I don't know. Random.

Comment: I somehow doubt it. I ran `window.location.href` in a loop and I got the same result every time. Doesn't seem random.

Comment: @VLAZ. This is the thing. if you do it from the console it will always return the full website URL. but if you using inside a script. It won't return full website URL in some of the cases. look here. happened to him also -? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102916/window-location-href-doesnt-yield-the-exact-url

Comment: The [`href` property is defined as returning the entire URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/href). If you're finding that it does not, that's a browser bug you should report to the maker of the browser. I'd encourage you to create a [mre], both for this question, and for any bug you report to a browser maker...

Comment: Are you pulling in a script that's hijacking/overwriting `window.location`, perhaps? Try removing things until it behaves normally. It's certainly not a normal browser behavior that you're describing.

Comment: @Jacob I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you wrote it as

```
domain = window.location.href;
```

I am 100% sure your variable is being overwritten by some third party script. If you are inside a function then use local variables initiating them with `var` or `let`. `let` has even smaller memory usage but was introduced in ES6 and not everyone has moved on to it. So `var` is your best bet here.

```
var domain = window.location.href;
```

Always use local variables when possible. It helps in avoiding these issues and keeps your memory usage low.

Comment: Thanks ;). Very simple solution!

Answer (score -3):

`window.location.hostname`

and `window.location.hostname` if you don't want to get the port (like http://localhost:3000/, `window.location.host = 'localhost:3000'` and `window.location.hostname = 'localhost'`

Comment: window.location.hostname return hostname. I need always get the website full URL.

Comment: I'm afraid this does not answer the question. The OP is asking for a property that always returns the full URL. They are complaining that it occasionally returns only the hostname, but that is not something they desire.