# Changing the colour of text copied to the clipboard from an HTML page

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, copy-paste

I have white text on a dark background on a web site. When the visitor copies this text and pastes it into an HTML aware word processor (like an email app), the text is copied white on white. I have adapted [this solution](http://bavotasan.com/2010/add-a-copyright-notice-to-copied-text/) by c.bavota to change the colour of the text and its background, applying [an IE9+ friendly change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12048577/1927589) suggested by KingKongFrog. You can see the effects in this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/lenevaxoqe/1/edit?html,css,js,output) demo, and you can find the full script below.

This works in Chrome and Safari and Opera on Mac, but it does not work on the latest Firefox (38.0.1). I haven't tested on any version of Internet Explorer yet.

With Firefox, if you paste into somewhere where styling is ignored (like the address bar of your email application), then the *text* will be pasted, so at least something is being copied.

Can you suggest changes that would persuade Firefox to let this work, too?

**EDIT: Do nothing on Firefox. Firefox already does all this for you, and better. The solution is to disable this script on Firefox, and all will be well.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html, body{
height: 100%;
margin: 0; 
color: #fff;
font-size: 32px;
background: #000;
}

div {
height: 100%;
}

span::selection {
color: #000;
background: #FFF;
}

span::-moz-selection {
color: #000;
background: #FFF;
}

.copy {
color: #000;
background: #FFF;
}
</style>


</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <p>
      <span>Select, then copy and paste this text </span>
      into an HTML aware word processor.
    </p>
  </div>

  <script>
  function blackOnWhite() {
    if (/mozilla/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()) && !/webkit/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()) {
      return;
    }
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var more = "<br /><br />More text"; // change this
    var copyDiv = document.createElement('div');
    copyDiv.style.position='absolute';
    copyDiv.style.left='-99999px';
    body.appendChild(copyDiv);
    copyDiv.innerHTML = selection + more;
    copyDiv.classList.add("copy");
    selection.selectAllChildren(copyDiv);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      body.removeChild(copyDiv);
    },1);
  }
  document.body.oncopy = blackOnWhite;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

On Mac you can paste unformatted with <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.